# Shortest path to connect n points

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

[image]

I have n points and I need to connect all of them minimizing the final distance. The image above represents an algorithm that in each node it connects to the nearest one but the final output might be really of.

I've been searching a lot, I know some pathfinding algos but unaware of one that solves exactly this case. I found a question on Math Stackexchange but the answer is not providing any algorithm - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/581844/156584.

Is there any algorithm that solves exactly this problem? Otherwise I can bruteforce it.

**Edit: Some clarification regarding the result I'm expecting: each node can be connected to 2 other nodes, creating a continuous path (like taking a pen and without ever lifting it, connect the nodes minimizing the final distance). I don't want to create a cycle (that being the travelling salesman problem).**

PS: this question can also be translated to "complete graph with n vertices, and wanting to choose the set of edges such that the graph is connected, but the sum of the edge weights is minimized"

Comment: "complete graph with n vertices, and wanting to choose the set of edges such that the graph is connected, but the sum of the edge weights is minimized" - The solution here is called `minimum spanning tree`, but MST and the *shortest path* problems are completely different!

Just in case you didn't see it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: It's the traveling salesman *path* problem, which is closely related to TSP in that many of the same techniques are applicable, in particular, dynamic programming and branch and bound.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is known as the shortest Hamiltonian path problem and it is NP-hard. So if the number of points is small, you can use backtracking or dynamic programming to find an optimal solution. If the number of points is large, you can use heuristics and/or approximations to obtain a relatively good answer(it is not always possible to find the best one in this case, though).

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference?  I would be interested.